# Laravel 5.4 - How I can get the correct relationship when model have 2 foreigns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables,

user_challenges

- id
- challenge_id
- user_id

user_scores

- id
- user_id
- challenge_id

user

- id
- name

challenge

- id
- title

How, in UserChallenge Model, I can get the user_scores value?

What is the correct relationship to can use in eagerloading.

I need something like this:

```
public function scores ()
{
return UserScore::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->where('challenge_id', $this->challenge_id);
}
```

Comment: relationship between what?

Comment: isn't this a simply belongsTo relationship?

Comment: So what is the difference between `user_challenges` and `user_scores`? They have same fields!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `->get()` call from the end of your query.

Try:

```
public function scores ()
{
    return UserScore::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->where('challenge_id', $this->challenge_id)->get();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work =/
returns me 

````
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.
````

Comment: Could you post the 4 complete model files for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship (afaik) for your setup. You seek a relationship between 2 pivot tables, which is pretty uncommon.

You have 2 possibilities here in my opinion:
1) Merge them into 1 table
2) user_scores should not have user_id and challenge_id, but one key user_challenges_id and should just be in a belongsTo relationship to user_challenges.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can get the user_scores when using the UserChallenge Model.
You can use a Query builder, like in your example. You just need to add `->get();` to that or it wont work.

Secondly, you can use the relations you defined.
Example:

`$userChallenge = UserChallenge::find(1);
return $userChallenge->user->user_scores`

If you have defined the relations properly every model can link to the next in a deeper level